# Redirect on Spring Tiles Causing Parameters to be Appended to the URL

Tags: spring, tiles, url-parameters

I am using Spring 3 and Tiles 3. Below is just a simplified example I made. I have a test controller where I list all the `SimpleEntity` objects. And there is an input field on the JSP to add a new entity via a POST. Here is the controller.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/test")
public class TestAdminController {

    private String TEST_PAGE = "admin/test";

    @Autowired
    private SimpleEntityRepository simpleEntityRepository;

    @ModelAttribute("pageName")
    public String pageName() {
        return "Test Administration Page";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("simpleEntities")
    public List<SimpleEntity> simpleEntities() {
        return simpleEntityRepository.getAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loadPage() {
        return TEST_PAGE;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addEntity(@RequestParam String name) {
        SimpleEntity simpleEntity = new SimpleEntity();
        simpleEntity.setName(name);
        simpleEntityRepository.save(simpleEntity);
        return "redirect:/" + TEST_PAGE;
    }

}
```

Everything works fine. However, when I submit the form, the URL adds the `pageName` parameter, so it goes from `/admin/test` to `/admin/test?pageName=Test+Administration+Page`. Is there anyway to prevent this from happening when the page reloads?

**UPDATE**

Here is the JSP form.

```
<form:form action="/admin/test" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" name="Save" />
</form:form>
```

Comment: what is the use of `@ModelAttribute("pageName")
    public String pageName() {
        return "Test Administration Page";
    }`

Comment: In the example, I just displayed it on the page via `${pageName}`.

Comment: Why don't you use `Model` to show these things??Then your controller will have only two methods one for `GET` another for `POST`. In that way you could stop this.

Comment: As mentioned, this is just an example. The real code is more complex and we need to do it this way.

Comment: can you post the `form` tag of your page?Just a guess.. I think you are using `commandName` or something there for `pageName` thats why while posting the form this is getting appended..